# Why isn't Jquery.globalEval working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to compute a user defined equation (a basic calculator), by appending the value of the spans clicked in a screen.
When I want to evaluate using the Jquery.GlobalEval, nothing seems to happen.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="screen"></div>


        <div class="keys">
            <!-- operators and other keys -->
            <span>7</span>
            <span>8</span>
            <span>9</span>
            <span>+</span>
            <span>4</span>
            <span>5</span>
            <span>6</span>
            <span>-</span>
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
            <span>/</span>
            <span>0</span>
            <span>.</span>
            <span class="eval">=</span>
            <span>x</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my jquery code:

```
jQuery(function() {

    // when C is clicked
    $(".clear").click(empty);
    var key;
    //any of the keys is clicked
    $(".keys span").not(".eval").click(function() {

        //======================
        if($(this).not(".eval")) {
            $('.screen').append($(this).html());
        }

        key = $('.screen').text().replace(/x/g, '*').replace('=', '');

    });


    $(".eval").click(function() {
        alert(calculate());
    });

    function empty() {
        $(".screen").empty();
    }
    function calculate() {
        jQuery.globalEval("var result = "+ key + ";");
    }
});
```

Thank you,

Comment: What is the error message? Notice, that your alert will always show `undefined`, since you're not returning anything from `calculate()`.

Comment: @Teemu it's not giving me an error message with this code, I'll edit for clarification. It just doesn't do anything

Comment: @Teemu yes it's giving me undefined when i place a return statement in calculate.

Comment: `.globalEval()` works fine in your code. You've to take care, that the string to eval is valid, otherway you'd get an error. And if you want to see the result in alert, you've to [`return result`](http://jsfiddle.net/7dg6482m/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to return the new variable, `result`. Try this (result output to console):

```js
jQuery(function() {

  // when C is clicked
  $(".clear").click(empty);
  var key;
  //any of the keys is clicked
  $(".keys span").not(".eval").click(function() {

    //======================
    if ($(this).not(".eval")) {
      $('.screen').append($(this).html());
    }

    key = $('.screen').text().replace(/x/g, '*').replace('=', '');

  });


  $(".eval").click(function() {
    console.log(calculate());
    alert(calculate());
  });

  function empty() {
    $(".screen").empty();
  }

  function calculate() {
   jQuery.globalEval("var result = " + key + ";");
   return result;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="screen"></div>


<div class="keys">
  <!-- operators and other keys -->
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>+</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>-</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>/</span>
  <span>0</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span class="eval">=</span>
  <span>x</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: where did you declare result?

Comment: Result is declared in `jQuery.globalEval("var result = " + key + ";");`.